# Iterate to Find Listobject in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I am trying to find a table ( ListObject ) from a excel workbook ( Lets say workbook 2 ) after opening the same through a VBA subroutine in another workbook ( Lets say workbook 1 ).

The code I tried is as follows ,

```
Sub B()
        Dim TBL_EMP As ListObject
        Dim strFile As Variant
        Dim WS_Count As Integer
        
        strFile = "File Path"
        Set WB_TRN = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
        
        WS_Count = WB_TRN.Worksheets.Count
        For n = 1 To WS_Count
                On Error GoTo Next_IT
                Set TBL_EMP = WB_TRN.Worksheets(n).ListObjects("EmployeeNameTbl")
                If Not TBL_EMP Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Object Found"
                End If
    Next_IT:
        Next n
    End Sub
```

When I run the subroutine it iterate only through 2 sheets and gives error code 9 " ( Subscript Out of Range ) eventhough workbook 2 has 10 worksheets.

If I open the workbook 2 through file open dialogue box then the code works fine.

Please help me to solve this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: That's not how error handling works in VBA. You should either iterate through the listobjects on the sheet and check each one's name, or use `On Error Resume Next` instead of your current line, with `On Error Goto 0` to reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Referencing a Table in a Workbook

**A 'Sub' Example**

```vb
Sub LocateTableExample()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Test\Test.xlsx"
    Const TableName As String = "EmployeeNameTbl"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            IsFound = True
            Exit For ' stop looping, it is found
        End If
    Next ws

    ' Continue using the 'tbl' and 'ws' variables.
    Debug.Print tbl.Name
    Debug.Print ws.Name

            
    If IsFound Then
        MsgBox "Table found in worksheet '" & ws.Name & "'.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Table not found.", vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Using a Function**

- The procedure `ReferenceTableTest` utilizes (calls) the following `ReferenceTable` function.

```vb
Sub ReferenceTableTest()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Test\Test.xlsx"
    Const TableName As String = "EmployeeNameTbl"
        
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ReferenceTable(wb, TableName)
    If tbl Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Debug.Print "Get the Names Using the 'tbl' variable"
    Debug.Print "Table Name:     " & tbl.Name
    Debug.Print "Worksheet Name: " & tbl.Range.Worksheet.Name
    Debug.Print "Workbook Name:  " & tbl.Range.Worksheet.Parent.Name
    
End Sub

Function ReferenceTable( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal TableName As String) _
As ListObject
    Const ProcName As String = "ReferenceTable"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            Set ReferenceTable = tbl
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Note that I just corrected a few minor mistakes mainly concerning the `TableName` constant. Sorry and thanks.